# Eclipse content assist with maven project not picking up all classes

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, content-assist

I'm using Eclipse 3.5.0, and have imported a maven project using the import maven project from SCM wizard (M2 plugin).

I have a jar file as a dependency in my pom. and inside the jar is a complicated schema - with quite a number of XSD's.  But the content assist doesn't seem to pick up the schema at all, nor a number of other classes in the dependency list.  yet for another module in the same project it seems to work ok.  Does anyone know why this is? it's driving me mad!

Comment: Do you have any more detail? For instance what are the paths to the xsds within the jars? (particularly contrast the working with the non-working module)

Comment: everything seems to be the same from what i can tell. (I'm relatively new to maven, just getting my head around it).  both have the dependency set the same in the pom.  there is one big difference that I can see - when its done the import from scm for the one that works its created a seperate module in the workspace as well as the module under simple-parent. and it hasn't for the one that hasn't worked,  could just be a coincidence though - both build viia the command line

Comment: what is in the separate module?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any details regarding the modules' structure, this workaround may help.

You can define **Catalog Contributions** to make Eclipse aware of schemas and allow them to contribute to content assist/validation.

- Open Window->Preferences->XML->XML Catalog
- Select **User Specified Entries** and **Add...**
- Add the path to Jar in the filesystem, then the relative path within the jar of the schema (e.g. c:.m2\repo\name\seller\rich\my-artifact\1.0\my-artifact-1.0.jar!\path\to\my\schema.xsd)
- Give it a key, this will be used as the default key in XML files using the schema
- Hit OK to get back to the editor.

You should now have the schema available for use in the editor, assuming you've defined your schema declarations correctly...

[image: XML Catalog Contributions]